# Reading the result of a Buck genrule into Buck

Tags: c++, buck

I am trying to use [buck](/questions/tagged/buck) to build [leveldb](/questions/tagged/leveldb). LevelDB has a [script that generates some platform-specific flags](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/build_detect_platform). I can call the script from Buck using a `genrule`, but now I need to extract some of the flags from the output.

```
genrule(
  name = 'build_config',
  out = 'build_config.mk',
  srcs = glob([
    'build_detect_platform',
    'db/**/*',
    'table/**/*',
    'util/**/*',
  ]),
  cmd = './build_detect_platform $OUT . ',
)
```

Is it possible to read the result of a target as a string into Buck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about using the genrule output as input to the Buck parser?  This isn't possible.

Comment: I believe so. I want to execute a `genrule`, read the output back into Python and generate further rules from the result. I realize that this may go against the declarative nature of Buck; I was just wondering if it is possible.

Comment: The only way you could do this is to generate header files that would be included that would change based on a platform.  As Mark says, it's impossible to change or add rules dynamically in Buck.